# How to show row have spacing in html?

Tags: html, html-table, row

My Code is......

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Row two doesn't show. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to hide a row it it has no characters in them? (aside from  whitespaces?)

Comment: Can you tell  your need in detail. or can you explain with an image ?

Comment: I need to show row, have whitespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td > &nbsp</td>
    <td >&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `<td>&nbsp;</td>` ?

Comment: I didn't see it coming. Thank you so much.